# Call 'super.loadUrl' inside a sub class

Tags: java, android, cordova

(First, let me state that my area of expertise is HTML5 (and php/coldfusion) and I am a beginner at Java/Android)

Inside my `onCreateOptionsMenu` I have the following code to handle a query change inside a search action in the android actionbar.

```
final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //I want to call super.loadUrl from here
            return true;
        }
};
```

The problem is that I want to call the loadUrl method of phonegap every time the text changes, however this isn't possible as `super` is seemingly referring to something else. I would probably be able to google this if I would even only know what the construction is called above (it seems to be some kind of sub class definition), but as I don't know even that and `super.super` isn't allowed I am at a total loss.

For reference: My class looks like

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
```

which is where the loadUrl comes from (I have also tried stuff in the direction of `DroidGap.loadUrl`).

Comment: What does your class hierarchy look like? Is what class is the queryTextListener method in?

Comment: As I edited my answer 10 minutes ago, `queryTextListener` is in `onCreateOptionsMenu` which is in my `MainActivity` which extends `DroidGap` (and DroidGap somehow exposes the loadUrl, though I am not sure how droidgap.java: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob_plain;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/DroidGap.java;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question might be missing some key points.  Super refers to the superclass of the current object.  In your case, the current object is queryTextListener, and super is a SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

**Edits based on comment below:**
In your containing method (same scope as final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener...) add a final ref to it, e.g.:

```
final DroidGap droidGap = this;
final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        droidGap.loadUrl(...);
        return true;
    }
```

};

Comment: My MainActivity extends DroidGap which somehow exposes loadUrl (though I can't find it in https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob_plain;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/DroidGap.java;hb=HEAD ... as I mentioned, I am fairly new at java, I get what super in general does, and I get as well that SearchView.OnQueryTextListener was somehow creating a class inside a class, but I have no clue how to get a reference to my 'original' parent class)

Comment: Thanks so much! That was exactly what I was expecting but had no clue how to do. I even tried some stuff along the lines of `... = super;` and I still don't get why this works (as in that same scope I have to use super.loadUrl and not this.loadUrl), but thanks incredibly much! :D

Comment: Yeah, this and super would have worked but you are creating and inner class in Java. That is why you have to assign this to droidGap before creating the class. That way the inner class can access the outer class.

Comment: To expand a bit on what Simon said, your code is executing in an instance method of the SearchView.OnQueryTextListener instance.  In the onQueryTextChange method, this refers to the SearchView.OnQueryTextListener instance and super would refer to the superclass of that.